# Setting default image size

Tags: images

I'm using WpeMatico plugin which saves images in the post using:

`$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $postid );`

I looked inside `wp-includes/post.php` > `wp_insert_attachment` function, but couldn't quite figure how to resize images. I want ALL/ANY images to have a max size of `1024` resize proportionately. I also have the resizing function, just not sure how to use it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original image size (i.e. 'full') is never modified. Intermediate image sizes are controlled in various places:

1. Default image sizes ( `'thumbnail'`, `'medium'`, `'large'` ): core settings, via **Dashboard -> Settings -> Media**
2. Custom image sizes: Theme `functions.php` file, via `add_image_size()`
3. Post Thumbnail size ( `'thumbnail'` ): Theme `functions.php file, via`set_post_thumbnail_size()`

By default, the `'large'` image size is constrained to **1024px**. So, you can simply output this image size where you need a 1024px image.

If you need to create a *custom* image size, you'll just need to *regenerate thumbnails* for existing images.

#### Edit

If you need/want to constrain the size of the `'full'` image size, then you'll need to modify it during the upload process, i.e. by hooking into `wp_handle_upload`, and performing the resize.

There are various Plugins that accomplish this. A quick search turns up:

- [Resize At Upload](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/resize-at-upload/)
- [Resize At Upload Plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/resize-at-upload-plus/)
- [Resize Images Before Upload](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/resize-images-before-upload/)
- [And many more...](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=upload%20resize)

Comment: All the options you mentioned resize the image only for DISPLAY, they don't actually "resize" the image to those dimensions, right? I want to resize the image on upload to reduce file size.

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, but again, those plugins won't help me because WpeMatico is uploading those images programmatically, I'm not uploading them manually myself so I could use those plugins.

Comment: Use a different Plugin, then? Or just use the core UI for image attachments?